# Log4j2 RollingFile appender sometimes not rolling over after midnight

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have a RollingFile appender

```
<RollingFile name="xxx" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/request.log" filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/request.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
  </Policies>
  <MarkerFilter marker="REQUEST_MARKER" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Which works perfect but this weekend at 14.02 and 15.02. the logger did not log anything after midnight between 00:00:00 and 03:39:17 and at 15.02. between 00:00:00 and 03:18:59.

Can anyone imagine why?

Btw: the application was okay, as I received data in other logfiles.

Regards
S.

Comment: So the first entry in the request.log.2015-02-14.1.gz file was at 03:39:17 ? Do your logfiles get big enough to roll-over by size? Or just by date usually?

Comment: 1. Yes, it was at 03:39:17. The rolloversize of the last file of the day before request.log.2015-02-14.1.gz was only 1.4M. The other files of the day before are 5M.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to look for.  Has this continued to happen daily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question is about not rolling over but your question makes it sound like you are asking why no logs were written during certain times, so I am not sure if I am answering your question.

The RollingFileAppender only checks for a rollover when it writes events. If no log event occurs between midnight and 3:18 am then the file will not roll over until 3:18 am.